# Is it possible to use nested item in .Rd?

Tags: r, rd

I can use \item to make a list in .Rd files.

```
\item{blah}{blah}
```

But it seems that I can not create a nested list by put \item within another `\item` as in

```
\item{blah}{
\item{blah1}{some}
\item{blah2}{thing}
}
```

Does anybody know a way to generate a nested list in R documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example (ignore the `#'` if you don't use roxygen):

```
#' \itemize{
#'   \item First level, itemize, first item
#'     \itemize{
#'       \item Second level, itemize, first item
#'       \item Second level, itemize, second item
#'         \enumerate{
#'           \item Third level, enumerate, first item
#'           \item Third level, enumerate, second item
#'         }
#'     }
#'   \item First level, itemize, second item
#' }
```

Which results in (I used it in a *Description* block):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use [roxygen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) to generate your documentation, this can be accomplished simply using rmarkdown.  The below code produces the same output as displayed in hrbrmstr's answer.

```
#' * First level, itemize, first item
#'   * Second level, itemize, first item
#'   - Second level, itemize, second item (- and * are equivalent)
#'     1. Third level, enumerate, first item
#'     2. Third level, enumerate, second item
#' * First level, itemize, second item
```